# A model GAM with deviance explained = 100%, AIC very low but no correlation is valid?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, deviance

I'm studying the correlation between the distribution of animals and environmental parameters using software R. I got as a result a model with deviance explained = 100 %; AIC very low but no correlation with parameters. Is possible? Can I explain this? it is possible that the data of the sightings are few?
Thank you for help!

Comment: You will have to be more specific and informative about your data if you expect a response. How is "distribution of animals" defined? What are the environmental parameters? Would you share the data?

Comment: Maybe you have more parameters than observations.